# Accessors/mutators

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create an object like this:

```
var DadosUtente = true;
var DevolucaoModelo = {
get UtNome() { return (DadosUtente) ? $("#UT_Nome") : $("#Equipamento_Nome")}
};
```

If i change the **DadosUtente** the selector returned changes too.

This works properly in Chrome, but when i've tested it with Internet Explorer i get an error because the browsers is excepting **:**

In the rest of code i'm accessing the selectors like DevolucaoModelo.UtNome.val();

Can someone help me?

By the way, i've search a lot in google and tried others solutions but without success in IE.

Comment: Is it JavaScript? JavaScript doesn't have a `get` keyword. http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

Comment: JavaScript Getters and Setters are not supported in IE; see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077106/javascript-getters-setters-in-ie

Comment: @Justin Oh, I didn't know about JavaScript Getters and Setters. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try:

```
var DadosUtente = true;
var DevolucaoModelo = {
    getUtNome : function() { return (DadosUtente) ? $("#UT_Nome") : $("#Equipamento_Nome")}
};
```

---

#### Update

If you don't want to call a function then do it like this:

```
var DadosUtente = true;
var DevolucaoModelo = {
    UtNome : (DadosUtente) ? $("#UT_Nome") : $("#Equipamento_Nome")
};
```

Then call it like `DevolucaoModelo.UtNome`.

Comment: Because i was looking for an alternative solution that doesn't involve to call an function

Comment: @guilhermeGeek: Accessors and mutators are functions. Just use a function. It'll save you grief, and there's no reason not to.

Comment: Shef that way doesn't work because if you change the "DadosUtente" to false, the object will keep returning the $("#UT_Nome") anyway.
I'll use functions instead, thanks ;)

Comment: @guilhermeGeek: If it should change after the first execution, of course you need the functions.

Comment: Yes mate it changes after the first execution. I guess i'm too used to C#, i really need to know better JS.
Thank you all the the replies ;)