# Error using javascript getters & setters in IE

Tags: javascript, oop, internet-explorer, getter-setter

I was reading [John Resig's article](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) about JavaScript Getters and Setters when I found this code:

```
function Field(val){
    this._value = val;
}
Field.prototype = {
    get value(){
        return this._value;
    },
    set value(val){
        this._value = val;
    }
};
```

I've tested and it works perfectly with all major browsers, except the damn IE, which gives me the `SCRIPT1003: ':' expected` error. After wondering for a while, I realized that this error happens because IE doesn't recognize JavaScript Getters and Setters, so I thinks that `get value` and `set value` are a syntax error.

Is there any way to make this code cross-browser?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**:

I also tried to check if the browser supports getters&setters:

```
if(window.__lookupSetter){
    Field.prototype = {
        get value(){
            return this._value;
        },
        set value(val){
            this._value = val;
        }
    };
}else{
    Field.prototype = {
        value: function(val){
            if(val)
                return this._value = val;
            return this._value;
        }
    };
}
```

But before executing the code, IE checks for syntax errors, and it wrongly finds these errors in the `get` and `set` lines.

Comment: which version of IE? This works in IE9. Getters and setters are not supported properly in earlier versions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript getters/setters in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077106/javascript-getters-setters-in-ie)

Comment: Then your page is running in compatibility mode. Try adding a `<!doctype html>` to the top of your HTML, if you don't already have one.

Comment: @Eric no, it's not duplicated because I'm not working with DOM elements

Comment: Getters and setters _only work on DOM elements_ in IE8.

Comment: @Eric I know, but my problem is that even if I put an `if` statement to check if the browser is the IE, the erros persists

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13256/discussion-between-eric-and-mark-linus)

Comment: This code works fine for me on IE9. If you open the console, is the document mode set to IE9?

Comment: The problem is not only IE9, but all older browsers that think that get an set are syntax errors, even if I put then inside an if statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define properties without using new syntax with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
function Field(val){
    this.value = val;
}
Object.defineProperty(Field.prototype, 'value', {
    get: function(){
        return this._value;
    },
    set: function(val){
        this._value = val;
    }
});
```

That way, the code won't give a syntax error in older browsers.

---

WRT to your edit, your fallback code:

```
Field.prototype = {
    value: this._value
};
```

Will not work. `this` will point to the global object - `window`.

---

The only way to truly use getters and setters cross browser is not to use them at all:

```
Field.prototype = {
    getValue: function() {
        return this._value;
    },
    setValue: function(val) {
        this._value = val;
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting the ECMA5 method - easily the best getter/setter implementation JavaScript has ever had. In case it helps the questioner, I wrote [a blog post](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Mar/JavaScript-getters-and-setters-varying-approaches-204) on this approach vs. older approaches which may or may not help.

Comment: @Utkanos the link is broken.

Comment: as of this comment link is broken.