# JavaScript, unknown syntax

Tags: javascript, function

I'm using the library handsontable and I'd like to get my application running in IE8-IE9 (even though it's not IE < 10 compatible...). When my code use the minify version I get an error in the JS console : "';' expected".

Here is the code.

```
, {
    get DEFAULT_WIDTH() {
        return 50;
    }
}
```

I just don't know this syntax. What does "get DEFAULT_WIDTH()" do ?

Comment: seems to return a default width == 50.

Comment: This function return 50. Perhaps the programmer created this function to avoid use magical numbers.

Comment: well I'm not sure but I think return an int with the value 50 :-) Like Sapikelio said, a default number

Comment: it's a getter/setter family. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077106/javascript-getters-setters-in-ie

Comment: It's a getter for a property called DEFAULT_WIDTH

Comment: Ypu are geting error in ie 8/9 ? IE of lower version, very sensetive to ";"

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, please check the answer that helped you most to understand the topic.If not, let us know what is missing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The `get` syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

The more general and exhausting explanation can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters

Basically, it allows you to define what happens when a certain object property is **read** by code. In an analogous fashion, you can also define what should happen when code **writes** to that property with a `set` definition. In both cases you overwrite the standard behaviour for that object property.

This is all part of ECMAScript 5.1, and thus, not available in IE < 9.

### What does your example code do?

In your example code, you can see that whenever the property DEFAULT_WIDTH is read, a *constant* value will be returned. I guess the intention of this is to make sure DEFAULT_WIDTH cannot be redefined as some other value (which it in fact can, but reading it will still return 50).

> ### Defining a getter on existing objects using defineProperty
>
> To append a getter to an existing object later at any time, use `Object.defineProperty()`.
>
> `var o = { a:0 }`
>   `Object.defineProperty(o, "b", { get: function () { return this.a + 1; } });`
>   `console.log(o.b) // Runs the getter, which yields a + 1 (which is 1)`
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Defining_a_getter_on_existing_objects_using_defineProperty

Answer (score 1):

MDN has documentation for [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), including a list of supporting browsers. What get does is invoke a function when the property is looked up. See [Defining getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) for a more general explanation.

Comment: probably easier to read the [high level definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) first.