# When functionality is not supported by browser, How can I know if a polyfill or Babel plugin exists? e.g: accessors

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) that getters are not supported in IE.

How can I know if some polyfills/Babel plugins exist so I can use it in my webapp?

Comment: You can't polyfill syntax. You'd have to compile your new JavaScript to old with e.g. babel.

Comment: Are you using computed property names?  Otherwise, getters have been supported since IE 9.

Comment: Refer to here also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077106/javascript-getters-setters-in-ie

Comment: I can't see in babel website that they're compiling getters & setters

Comment: As noted in the very page you linked, unless you absolutely require to use `get`, the `defineProperty()` method has very similar behaviour and is supported across all browsers and versions.

Comment: You're right, maybe I will use the defineProperty() method, but I also asking in a more global way.
When some functionality is not supported how can I know if a pollyphill or babel can help

Comment: It's a babel plugin for this -> https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es5-property-mutators.html

Comment: @IsraGab in general the best way to do this is to use something like [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) to figure out what you need. I generally have around 3-4 "tiers" of polyfill bundles and load them based on need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be misunderstood something. On page you've mentioned it says, that getters/setters are supported starting from IE 9 (so, should be also available in IE 11). Check [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Browser_compatibility) section.

However get/set syntax is just Syntactic sugar over old [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). For example:

```
var bValue = 38;
var o = {
  get b () { return bValue; },
  set b (newValue) { bValue = newValue; }
}
```

equals to:

```
var o = {}; // Creates a new object
var bValue = 38;
Object.defineProperty(o, 'b', {
  get() { return bValue; },
  set(newValue) { bValue = newValue; },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
console.log(o.b); // 38
```

So, you can use that, if you really need it like that.

As [Jared Smith well pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065813/when-functionality-is-not-supported-by-browser-how-can-i-know-if-a-polyfill-or/52066513#comment91103803_52066513) it's technically possible to detect at runtime wether new syntax is supported by using `eval` (another option would be to pass your code as a string into `new Function`).
Anyway, it's not the best way of dealing with old browsers, so if you want to write your code using ES6 syntax, but be able to use it in older browsers, use tools like babel, which will transform your code properly, so it will be supported by older browsers.

Comment: Note that it *is* technically possible to check if a syntax is available at runtime using `eval` (and this is arguably one of the few legitimate use cases for `eval`).